# Is there something like a Safe Navigation Operator that can be used on Arrays?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, safe-navigation-operator

I have used Safe Navigation Operator for Objects to load on Asynchronous calls and it is pretty amazing. I thought I could reproduce the same for Arrays but it displays a template parse error in my Angular code. I know `*ngIf` is an alternative solution, but is there a more simpler(by code) way just like the Safe Navigation Operator?

```
<div class="mock">
   <h5>{{data?.title}}</h5>  //This works
   <h6>{{data?.body}}</h6>  //This works
   <h6>{{simpleData?[0]}}</h6>  // This is what I tried to implement    
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a more simpler(by code) way just like the Safe Navigation Operator?

There is [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

```
<h6>{{simpleData?simpleData[0]:''}}</h6>
```

Comment: This tends to become very unreadable when you have rather complex, deep data:
`((a?.b||[])[13]?.c||[])[7]` instead of `a?.b?.[13]?.c?.[7]` in modern ECMAscript

Comment: While not exactly Angular-specific, you could also use lodash to safely retrieve more deeply nested objects.

e.g. `get myData() { return _.get(this.thing, 'a[0].b.c'); }`
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Answer (score 39):

> Is there something like a Safe Navigation Operator that can be used on Arrays?

Yes, what you are looking for is known as the **Optional Chaining** operator ([JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax) / [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)).

The syntax shown in the MDN JavaScript documentation is:

```
obj.val?.prop
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.arr?.[index]
obj.func?.(args)
```

So, to achieve what you want, you need to change your example from:

```
<h6>{{simpleData?[0]}}</h6>
```

To:

```
<h6>{{simpleData?.[0]}}</h6>
                 ^
```

Also see [How to use optional chaining with array in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59623674/1497596).

Comment: for anyone looking this is the latest and this can be used in component logic as well.

Answer (score 8):

Of cause it's a matter of taste, but in such cases I tend to use a shorter approach:

```
<h6>{{(simpleData || [])[0]}}</h6>
```

Comment: but it is empty array, so accessing first element will fail anyway?

Comment: No it won't. Reading non-existing element returns `undefined` which is translated to an empty result by Angular.

Comment: Some might consider using the [Nullish Coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to now be considered a better practice: `(simpleData ?? [])[0]`. That said, the now available [Optional Chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax) offers a more direct solution to the stated question.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers amount to the same thing, but I find `foo && foo[0]` to be the most readable. The right side of the logical-and operator won't be evaluated if the left side is falsy, so you safely get `undefined` (or I guess `null`, if you don't believe Douglas Crockford.) with minimal extra characters.

For that matter, you asked for a "simpler" solution, but actually `*ngIf` is probably correct for the use case you gave.  If you use any of the answers here, you'll wind up with an empty `h6` tag that you didn't need.  If you make the tag itself conditional, you can just put `foo[0]` in the handlebars and be confident that it won't be evaluated when `foo` is still undefined, plus you never pollute the page with an empty tag.