# How can I use optional chaining with arrays and functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, optional-chaining

I'm trying to use optional chaining with an array instead of an object but not sure how to do that:

Here's what I'm trying to do `myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey)?[0]`.
Also trying similar thing with a function:

```
let x = {a: () => {}, b: null}
console.log(x?b());
```

But it's giving a similar error - how can I use optional chaining with an array or a function?

Comment: What input data do you have, and what results do you want?

Comment: That's a generic question shouldn't depend on input and output `?` does a null check to prevent long use of `&&` `&&` chains.

Answer (score 536, accepted):

You need to put a `.` after the `?` to use optional chaining:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey)?.[0]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwCoFNoGkUJgXhgcgCMBDAJ3wG4BYAKFElkQEFTTjs8BtAbxijSiYEALgIAzECHwwAvgBoYvfhiyiiZaTIC61OuGgxSaAK4AbWHmat2AOjEBLcylIAKAB64AfDDc3lgrFwcS2QBIQBKAH4bTgAGHVp6CBBTFBtTEABzFyMIMyhwiiA)

Using just the `?` alone makes the compiler think you're trying to use the conditional operator (and then it throws an error since it doesn't see a `:` later)

Optional chaining isn't just a TypeScript thing - it is a finished proposal [in plain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) too.

It can be used with bracket notation like above, but it can also be used with dot notation property access:

```js
const obj = {
  prop2: {
    nested2: 'val2'
  }
};

console.log(
  obj.prop1?.nested1,
  obj.prop2?.nested2
);
```

And with function calls:

```js
const obj = {
  fn2: () => console.log('fn2 running')
};

obj.fn1?.();
obj.fn2?.();
```

Comment: This also works for Javascript (since 2020 I think). Similarly, to call a function if it isn't `null` or `undefined`, you can also use `foo?.()`

Answer (score 46):

Just found it after a little searching on the what's new page on [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

The right way to do it with array is to add `.` after `?`

so it'll be like

```
myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey)?.[0] // in case of object
x?.() // in case of function
```

I'll like to throw some more light on what exactly happens with my above question case.

```
myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey)?[0]
```

**Transpiles to**

```
const result = myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey) ? [0] : ;
```

Due to which it throws the error since there's something missing after : and you probably don't want your code to be transpilled to this.

Thanks to Certain Performance's answer I learned new things about typescript especially the tool https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html .

Answer (score 32):

ECMA 262 (2020) which I am testing on Edge Chromium 84 can execute the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator without TypeScript transpiler:

```
// All result are undefined
const a = {};

console.log(a?.b);
console.log(a?.["b-foo-1"]);
console.log(a?.b?.());

// Note that the following statements throw exceptions:
a?.(); // TypeError: a is not a function
a?.b(); // TypeError: a?.b is not a function
```

[CanIUse: Chrome 80+, Firefox 74+](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining)

Comment: This is THE solution - why are others using it withe looping methods ? -  I got it solved using `obj?.people?.p15?.results?.science`

Comment: @anjanesh they are answering the specific question by OP. No other answer is using loop btw unless you count internal loop `filter` method.

Comment: Wouldn't `filter` take more time and optional chaining ?

Answer (score 15):

It's not necessary that the function is inside the object, you can run a function using optional chaining also like this:

```
someFunction?.();
```

If `someFunction` exists it will run, otherwise it will skip the execution and it will not error.

This technique actually is very useful especially if you work with reusable components and some components might not have this function.

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls)

Comment: Came here for this. In my head the operator was just adding the `?` to the `.` acessor already so I naively assumed the correct syntax was `someFunction?()`. I must admit, the `?.()` does look a little weird, as if you are "accessing" the function instead of invoking it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even though we figured out the correct syntax, the code doesn't make much sense to me.

The optional chaining in the code above is making sure, that the result of `myArray.filter(x => x.testKey === myTestKey)` is not `null` and not `undefined` (you can have a look at the TS output). But it is not possible anyway, because the result of the `filter` method is always an `array`. Since JavaScript doesn't throw "Array bounds exceeded", you are always safe when you try to access any index - you will get `undefined` if this element doesn't exist.

More example to make it clear:

```
const myArray: string[] = undefined
console.log(myArray.filter(x => x)?.[0]) //throws Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

```
//in this example the optional chaining protects us from undefined array
const myArray: string[] = undefined
console.log(myArray?.filter(x => x)[0]) //outputs "undefined"
```