# How to check for empty array result in single line filter method, I want to add validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

`let x = this.currentList.filter((x) => x.Tab == this.currentTab)[0].TabSequence;`

I want to add ?(validation) operator on filter result if I get empty result. Please find below. How I can handle if result is empty array then [0].TabSequence

`let x = this.currentList.filter((x) => x.Tab == this.currentTab)?[0].TabSequence;`

Comment: the syntax is `...)?.[0].Tab...` and you don't need `filter` in this case, it is better to go with `find`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623674/how-can-i-use-optional-chaining-with-arrays-and-functions

Comment: Site note: `filter(...)[0]` is the same as `find(...)`. Why not use `find`instead?

Comment: my main motive is about optional chaining, that I understood